# Django - how to use multilevel join in models

Tags: django-models, django-queryset

I am beginner in python-Django and I am trying to build a e-commorce site. I have created a model for product Detail and product images.
Here is my models:

```
class ProductDetail(models.Model):        
    product= models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category= models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_category= models.ForeignKey(ProductSubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    created_at= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=datetime)
    updated_at= models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    deleted_at= models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.product

class ProductImage(models.Model):      
    img_type_choices = (
        ('Primary', "Primary"),
        ('Secondary', "Secondary"),
    )  
    product= models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img= models.FileField(upload_to="shop/product_images", default="")
    type= models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=img_type_choices, default='Primary')
    created_at= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=datetime)
    updated_at= models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    deleted_at= models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I using below code for products:

```
from shop.models import ProductSubCategory, ProductImage, ProductCategory, Product, ProductDetail

def index(request):
   products = ProductDetail.objects.values('product__name','product__product_id', 'product__price', 'product__desc', 'category__name', 'sub_category__name', 'category')
```

Now I want all images with product object

Now I am not getting how to get all images related to a products along with these object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using `.values()`. It get rid of the Model layer by outputing dicts which make you loose a lot of Model capabilities.

I would do something like this:

```py
qs = ProductDetail.objects.all()
qs = qs.select_related("product", "category", sub_category)
qs = qs.prefetch_related("product__productimage_set")
```

`.select_related()` will results in SQL joins which make `product_detail.product` accessible without additional query. This is very powerful to retrieve related models.

`.prefetch_related()` provide similar benefit but with reverse foreign keys. (At the cost of 1 SQL query per model).
Accessing `product_detail.product.productimage_set.all()` will give you all ProductImages tied to `product_detail.product` without needing additional queries.

Note that `productimage_set` is the default `related_name` generated by Django. You can define your own.

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):      
    product= models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
```

Comment: thanks #Alombaros, for clearing select_related and prefetch_related. Now it's resolve

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct so it gets out of the unresolved questions